# Accessing other models through foreign keys in Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to Python and Django and I'm trying to make my first small web app. I have two models, with a one-to-many foreign key in Event. Here's what I have so far

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    seats = models.IntegerField()
    tickets = ???

class Ticket(models.Model):
    seat = models.IntegerField()
    eventReference = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

I'm assuming this is how I do it. One event can have multiple tickets. I create a foreign key to Ticket so that it's possible. However, I would like to access all the tickets straight from the Event model attribute tickets. I found some examples of following relationships "backwards", but none of them could be applied to this. So if I want Event's tickets-attribute to contain all tickets related to that event, what should I put there? Something like this? I'm quite confused.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    seats = models.IntegerField()
    tickets = Event.objects.get(this??).ticket.entry_all.get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all tickets for an event, you do:

```
event = Event.objects.get(id=1)
tickets = event.ticket_set.all()
```

You shouldn't define anything special for `tickets`, because django's default model manager has taken care of that.

[Django doc about following reverse foreignkey relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Comment: Can I actually have a tickets-attribute in the Event-class then?

Comment: You have it already: that is what `ticket_set` is, Django defines it for you automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. If I set tickets = ticket_set, I get NameError: name 'ticket_set' is not defined.

Comment: I don't think so, `ticket_set` is the default manager associated with `Event`,  you need to use it on an `event` object. You don't define it in your class. The code I showed you can be used anywhere(views.py, django shell, etc).

Comment: In other words, your model is perfect if you get rid of `tickets = ???`, there's nothing to add to your model.

Comment: Oh I see, I had the wrong idea all the way. Got it working without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    seats = models.IntegerField()

class Ticket(models.Model):
    seat = models.IntegerField()
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

Views.py

```
event= Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
event.ticket_set.all()
```

If you get all tickets from template

```
event.ticket_set.all
```

`ticket` is an `Ticket` model instace

```
{% for ticket in event.ticket_all %} 
...
...
{% endfor%}
```